# Commands given for cmake and doxygen in _vimrc give error on gvim start up?

Tags: c++, c, vim, vim-plugin

I am a beginner to vim and just downloaded the c-support plugin (for C/C++ programming) from the following link: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213

As advised in the link, to enable cmake and doxygen, i added the following lines to my _vimrc:

`let  g:C_UseTool_cmake    = 'yes'
 let  g:C_UseTool_doxygen = 'yes'`

However, now when I start up gvim, I get the following error message dialog:

```
Could not load the tool "cmake" (Vim(let):E117: Unknown function: mmtoolbox#make#Interface)- occurred at C:\Users\Satyendra\Vim\vimfiles\autoload\mmtoolbox\cmake.vim, line 219
```

My OS is Windows 10. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Looks like an error in c.vim. The best is to contact the author or open an issue or the project forge.

Comment: @LucHermitte I will do that. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Sorry I cannot do more (I'm maintaining an alternative solution for C++, and thus I not using c.vim -- I wasn't even aware they introduced a support for CMake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I [opened an issue](https://github.com/WolfgangMehner/vim-plugins/issues/33) on C-Support's Github page, and the problem was solved.